# Is it OK for RSA public key to have some most significant bits = 0?

Tags: rsa

I work with a smart card which is able to generate RSA keys. But when I generate a key pair, the new generated public and private keys can have some of their most significant bits = 0. Is this OK or does it mean less cryptographic strength?

Comment: I don't understand why you think this would be less secure. 0 is just as valid as 1, right?

Comment: @tenfour surely by that logic, 3 is a perfectly good 1024 bit prime, if you put 1022 zero bits in front of it.

Comment: It's natural for randomness to produce a bunch of repeated values when the only valid values are 0 and 1. In this context, "some bits" is very different from 1022.

Answer (score 1):

In some representations, the MSB must be zero, otherwise the value well get treated as a negative number. It should have sufficient non-zero bits such that the modulus is of the size you wanted to generate, otherwise, yes it is less secure.